# A point P in a complex example with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, mdframed

I discover the `mdframed` package today and the examples with TikZ.

In these examples there is a complex example with TikZ  and a  point `P` is used for positionning the title of the exercise.
I suppose that this point is defined in the macro and it is the  right top corner. 
Is it possible tu use the   right lower  corner and what is its name?

Thank you for  your answer.

Best regards

Comment: Welcome. How do you expect we help you with you don't show even the code for example? Please, edit and insert the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mdframed` assigns two special coordinates to a frame which basically is a rectangle:

- `(P)` Upper right corner.
- `(O)` Lower left corner.

The other two vertices can be accessed using the perpendicular coordinate system:

- `(O|-P)` Upper left corner; it can also be accessed using `(P-|O)`.
- `(P|-O)` Lower right corner; it can also be accessed using `(O-|P)`.

Here you can see them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[
singleextra={
  \foreach \Coor/\Pos in {O/below,P/above,O|-P/above,P|-O/below} 
    \node[\Pos,font=\ttfamily] at (\Coor) {(\Coor)};
}
]
test text
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

The result, showing the coordinates:

[image]

Loading the `calc` library allows you then to access other special coordinates. The following example shows how to aceess the middle points of the four sides of the frame:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{mdframed}[
singleextra={
    \node[overlay,inner sep=1.5pt,circle,fill] at ( $ (O|-P)!0.5!(P) $ ) {};
    \node[overlay,above,font=\ttfamily] at ( $ (O|-P)!0.5!(P) $ ) {( \$ (O|-P)!0.5!(P) \$ )};
    \node[overlay,inner sep=1.5pt,circle,fill] at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) $ ) {};
    \node[overlay,below,font=\ttfamily] at ( $ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) $ ) {( \$ (O)!0.5!(P|-O) \$ )};
    \node[overlay,inner sep=1.5pt,circle,fill] at ( $ (O)!0.5!(O|-P) $ ) {};
    \node[overlay,left,font=\ttfamily] at ( $ (O)!0.5!(O|-P) $ ) {( \$ (O)!0.5!(O|-P) \$ )};
    \node[overlay,inner sep=1.5pt,circle,fill] at ( $ (P)!0.5!(P|-O) $ ) {};
    \node[overlay,right,font=\ttfamily] at ( $ (P)!0.5!(P|-O) $ ) {( \$ (P)!0.5!(P|-O) \$ )};
  }  
]
test text
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: @GarcinJean-Louis You're welcome.